# How to copy lines from multiple files into one new file and keep file name?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, filenames, file-copy

I have 81 files in .fasta format that contain (up to) 53 items. Such as:

```
/User/MyData/Sample_1.fasta
/User/MyData/Sample_2.fasta
....
/User/MyData/Sample_81.fasta
```

Each .fasta file contains a name ID and string of characters delimited as:

```
>AT1G00001
ATCCACTGCTGTGTACCTGATCAGTGCTGACCCAYTGTGACACTGTG
>AT2G00002
AAAAATTTTGCCCGTGTGGGCCAAACTGTCATGCATGCACCGTACGTGCATGCAT
....
>ATXGXXXXX(up to 53)
AAACCCTCTTTGTGCCTGTGCATGCA
```

I would like to copy strings from each of my 81 .fasta files into a new .fasta file such that:

```
/User/MyData/AT1G00001.fasta
/User/MyData/AT2G00002.fasta
....
/User/MyData/ATXGXXXXX.fasta
```

And the content of one of these contains (after copying from all 'Sample_X.fasta' files in the directory):

```
>Sample_1
ATCCACTGCTGTGTACCTGATCAGTGCTGACCCAYTGTGACACTGTG
>Sample_2
ATCGACTCCCGTAGGACTGATTTTTCTGACCCCATTGTGACACTGTG
....
>Sample_81
TTCTGACCCCATTGTGACACTGTGATCGACTCCCGTAGGACTGATTT
```

I've come across one or two similar questions, but nothing with exactly the nuance of preserving the SampleName in the copied output file and am having some difficulty getting examples from similar but different questions to work.

Thank you so much for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the following code for you; below it there's an explanation how it works.

First go into the working directory (`cd /User/MyData/`) to run this program:

```
awk '
  FNR==1 { sample = FILENAME ; sub(/\.fasta/, "", sample }
  /^>/   { target = substr($0,2)".fasta" ; next }
         { print ">" sample > target ; print > target }
' Sample_*.fasta
```

The `awk` program iterates over all `Sample_*.fasta` files. At start of each input file (`FNR==1`) it extracts the sample name from the current filename by removing the suffix ".fasta". If a line starts with `>` then the target filename for that record is taken from after the `>` character, and the filename suffix ".fasta" appended. For the other type of lines the previously extracted sample name is written to the target file, and in a second line the current data is written.

Note: If you observe problems with "too many open file descriptors" then the best choice is to switch to GNU `awk` if possible!

If GNU `awk` is not or can not be made available on your platform then you need a couple of additional changes; the key is to close each file after writing to it, by using the `close()` function, with the consequence that you have to append to the closed files. (This is more complex and also less performant, so it's worth thinking about getting GNU `awk` and use the first variant.)

Those changes would then result in a program like:

```
# because of the append operation you need to empty the file targets
# before calling subsequent awk code, e.g. by: rm -f AT???????.fasta
awk '
  FNR==1 { sample = FILENAME ; sub(/\.fasta/, "", sample }
  /^>/   { target = substr($0,2)".fasta" ; next }
         { printf ">%s\n%s\n", sample, %0 >> target ; close(target) }
' Sample_*.fasta
```

Note that before you call the `awk` program you have to make sure to remove or empty any existing output-files from previous calls (otherwise your new output would get appended to the data previously existing in the respective output file(s).

Comment: Basically we came up with the same solution, although for the redirection `>>` should be used.

Comment: @FloHinself; No, in `awk` it is sufficient and correct to write `>` as redirection to **once** create the file on start. (Using `>>` would lead to wrong results in case that the target file is already existing or if you run the program twice without removing the previous file.)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying about the `>` operator, I didn't know it works this way in `awk`! Note the regex in the `sub()` call should use an anchor, otherwise a filename like `Sample_1.fastasample.fasta` will give strange results.

Comment: @FloHimself; Thanks; the filenames are well specified in the question, so there's no need for that.

Comment: Well this would leed to _a potential issue if_ files will be added.

Comment: @FloHimself; Now this is getting silly! The syntax is already well defined; even if you add new files there's no problem. - I suggest to use the time you spend for nonsensical comments like this one for pondering about the real issues.

Comment: I just used your argument...

Comment: @FloHimself; No, you tried, but you didn't. - As a service for you I re-quote myself: *(but doesn't hurt in this case)*; I said this from the beginning. - Though this mitigation has **not** addressed the `>>` part; here I said: *keep it as you like* (with explanations matching the actual requirements given).

Comment: FIrst of all, wow! Thank you so much, @Janis ! The awk program seems to work great, there is just one exception for files that I get an error in awk: "(target).fasta makes too many open files input record number 36, file Sample_X.fasta"

It looks like I need to add some 'close' in the function?

Comment: Aha, I fixed my previous 'close' issue by changing line four to read: 
             { print ">" sample > target ; print > target; close(target) }
Now it seems I get multiple of the same 'target' files for each 'sample_.fasta'. Is there a way to concatenate the target output to the same .fasta when the target is the same? I tried simply adding 'cat', but am getting an error (unfamiliar with nuances of awk!)

Comment: @MoGo; There's two choices, actually; I added a note to my answer. My choice would be to switch to GNU `awk` (if possible), but otherwise see for the additionally necessary steps in my answer.

Comment: @Janis Thanks again – solution to first issue worked like a charm ('too many open...')! One final issue is that I get multiple printed .fasta files for each target name (e.g., I have two files named AT1G00001.fasta; one contains data for this target from Sample_1 and the other contains data for this target from Sample_2). Is there a way to print all targets that match the same target name (e.g., AT1G00001) to the same .fasta file? Thanks again so much for introducing me to awk!

Comment: @MoGo; I don't understand what you mean by having *"two files named AT1G00001.fasta"*; in the same directory of the same file system there can only be *one* instance of a file with a unique name. Please explain your situation.

Comment: @Janis Aha! Perfect. I was being quite stupid. I had exported one .fasta file with underscores in the name and others without underscores. The files are actually more like "ATXGXXXXX_Read1_Consensus.fasta" so in one of the sets of files I had "ATXGXXXXX_Read1_Consensus.fasta" and in the other "ATXGXXXXX Read1 Consensus.fasta". Just stupidity on my part – everything works perfectly now, thank you SO MUCH!

Answer (score 0):

Although it would be interesting to know what you've tried so far, here is an example how `awk` could be used for this job:

```
awk '
    FNR == 1 {
        sub(/\.fasta$/, "", FILENAME)
    }
    /^>/ && sub(/^>/, "") {
        newfile = $0 ".fasta"
        next
    }
    {
        print ">" FILENAME >> newfile
        print $0 >> newfile
    }' Sample_*.fasta
```

Comment: While similar to my solution this one has two caveats that should be noted. One is that it wrongly appends to the file `>>` instead of newly creating it; `>` should be used. (Mind that `awk` redirection works different than shell redirection!) And second, it is not optimal (but doesn't hurt in this case) to overwrite existing variables (`FILENAME` and `$0`); in case the script will be extended that may lead to surprises.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I didn't know that `>` worked this way in `awk`. So it depends on how the OP will use the script then. I thought overwriting build-in variables is a commonly used feature in `awk` as in `$1 = ""; print $0` to print all but the first field...

Comment: As said, the overwriting of those variables is only a potential issue if the script will be extended. I just wouldn't change predefined variables like `FILENAME`. Code like `$1=""` is even more a problem, because it changes the spacing of the input data and so `$0` (i.e. in $0 the spaces between the fields), which you may not want reformatted. - WRT the redirection it's definitely `>` that should be used! (The `>>` does only open gaps for unnecessary problems, so avoid it here.) I suggest to fix that detail in your answer.

Comment: I don't see a problem here in overwriting the build-ins, extensibility is cleary not an requirement here. With the change from `>>` to `>`, the script has to be called with all files given. A later call to the script will overwrite the previously written file.

Comment: Even in case that a second call of the script will be made; your version will **add** duplicate records to the already created files. Where if using `>` you will always have a consistent result. - Anyway; keep it as you like. I noted the caveats and explained them, so folks will know what they get.

Comment: Yes, that would be obvious if used with `>>`. The files have to be removed then. I guess, the problems of both variants are discussed very well now, so everyone can change to their needs.

Answer (score 0):

Some shell: this will be much slower than an awk program.

```
cd /User/MyData
for sample in Sample*.fasta; do
    sample_name=${sample%.fasta}
    while read name; read data; do
        name=${name#>}
        printf ">%s\n%s\n" "$sample_name" "$data" >> "$name.fasta"
    done < "$sample"
done
```

Comment: This also works! It's not noticeably slower for the size of files I'm working with, but I do encounter the same problem that I did above, with the awk program. Each "sample.fasta" produces a separate file for each data line "ATXGXXXXXX". What I need most is a single .fasta for each "ATXGXXXXX". Most samples contain the same set of named data (e.g., Samples 1 and 2 both contain a string of characters for AT1G000001 and AT2G000002. However, when I run these scripts for a folder with only two Sample_.fasta files I get two files named "AT1G000001" and two files names "AT2G000002".

Comment: @MoGo; For larger data shell loops are known to be slow. But (the observed discrepancy aside for a moment) depending on the magnitude of the degradation (i.e. if it's not too large) of the shell solution it may be worth to try running it in `ksh` (in case you tried with`bash`); there's a good chance that it's running significantly faster in `ksh`.

Comment: I figured it out in my comment above. I don't know how I didn't think about impossibility of two same-named files in same directory... works great, thank you so much! I did a full export (I was just working with a small subset of two of the Sample files to test the scripts before). The awk script is much faster for the full file set!